# TSQL Left and Inner Joins

Tags: t-sql, left-join, inner-join

Given the follow sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE People(PeopleID int, Name varchar(10))
INSERT INTO People VALUES(1, 'Chris')
INSERT INTO People VALUES(2, 'Cliff')
INSERT INTO People VALUES(3, 'Heather')

CREATE TABLE Things(ThingID int, ThingName varchar(10))
INSERT INTO Things VALUES(14, 'Bike')
INSERT INTO Things VALUES(17, 'Trailer')
INSERT INTO Things VALUES(18, 'Boat')

CREATE TABLE PeopleThings(PeopleID int, ThingID int)
INSERT INTO PeopleThings VALUES(1, 18)
INSERT INTO PeopleThings VALUES(2, 14)
```

...and the following query:

```
SELECT P.Name,
     T.ThingName
FROM People P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PeopleThings PT ON P.PeopleID = PT.PeopleID
    INNER JOIN Things T ON PT.ThingID = T.ThingID
```

I am wanting to see the following results:

```
|Name      |ThingName |
-----------------------
|Chris     |Boat      |
-----------------------
|Cliff     |Bike      |
-----------------------
|Heather   |(null)    |
-----------------------
```

I am wanting a list of everyone in the PEOPLE table, and the names of the THINGS they own (or if they own anything).  I know the issue is somewhere in my JOINs, but I'm not understanding/seeing where.  Please help.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I always write my inner joins adjacent. It basically builds a smaller and smaller set logically. The left joins are always after that and won't reduce the set size as long as you don't put references in your WHERE clause. I personally find this pattern effective in preventing an issue like this.

Comment: ON PT.ThingID breaks the left join.

Comment: Hi. Learn what left join returns--inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. And if you inner join after an outer join you are only going to get the usual result from inner join--rows made from the two inputs that satisfy the on.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer but I was working on it
`INNER JOIN Things T ON PT.ThingID` breaks the left join

You can keep the `inner join` but change the order of the `on`.
This might be more efficient than 2 `left join`.

```
declare @People TABLE (PeopleID int primary key, Name varchar(10));
INSERT INTO @People VALUES
       (1, 'Chris')
     , (2, 'Cliff')
     , (3, 'Heather');

declare @Things TABLE (ThingID int primary key, ThingName varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Things VALUES
       (14, 'Bike')
     , (17, 'Trailer')
     , (18, 'Boat');

declare @PeopleThings TABLE (PeopleID int, ThingID int, primary key (PeopleID, ThingID));
INSERT INTO @PeopleThings VALUES
       (1, 18)
     , (1, 17)
     , (2, 14);

SELECT P.Name, T.ThingName
FROM @People P
LEFT JOIN @PeopleThings PT   
     JOIN @Things T 
       ON PT.ThingID = T.ThingID 
  ON P.PeopleID = PT.PeopleID
order by P.Name, t.ThingName;

Name       ThingName
---------- ----------
Chris      Boat
Chris      Trailer
Cliff      Bike
Heather    NULL
```

Can also do it with a right join

```
SELECT P.Name, T.ThingName
FROM @PeopleThings PT
JOIN @Things T 
  ON PT.ThingID = T.ThingID 
right join @People P 
  ON P.PeopleID = PT.PeopleID 
order by P.Name, t.ThingName;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your query:

```
SELECT P.Name,
     T.ThingName
FROM People P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PeopleThings PT ON P.PeopleID = PT.PeopleID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Things T ON PT.ThingID = T.ThingID;
```